# Select all fields from a package datatype

Tags: oracle

If I have a custom recorddatatype looking like this, declared in a package spec:

```
TYPE t_params IS record(
param1 BOOLEAN,
param2 BOOLEAN,
param3 boolean);
```

Is there any views I can query from that would list up all the field/column names (param1, param2, param3)?

For example something like this: 
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_FIELDS
WHERE DATATYPE = 't_params'

Comment: You will need to define this type **in the schema** using `create type` statement, as well as a table type of this record. You'll be then able to use these record type in an SQL query or view. Moreover, `boolean` is not an SQL type, so you won't be able to use it in the custom type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 11g and lower, you can't. At least, not in a straightforward way.

In Oracle 12c, you can easily select from

- `user_plsql_types`
- `user_plsql_type_attrs`
- `user_plsql_coll_types`

**Edit:** Assuming that **only SQL-types** are in use in the record type (which is not the case with your record with booleans) in question, then in Oracle 11g you can do it with a funky workaround.

For the following example I'll use one of my packaged PL/SQL types, `rec_parse_dd_file_name_out` placed in the `utl_dd_intfc_file` package.

I'll create a "wrapper" package `wrapper_pkg` with

- one `wrapper_nt` type as a collection of the PL/SQL record type of my interest
- one table function `wrapper_tf` returning the pipelined `wrapper_nt` collection

Note: We don't need a package body for this experiment.

```
create or replace package wrapper_pkg
as

type wrapper_nt is table of utl_dd_intfc_file.rec_parse_dd_file_name_out;

function wrapper_tf return wrapper_nt pipelined;

end;
/
```

Now, querying the `user_arguments` for result type of the `wrapper_pkg.wrapper_tf()` table function ...

```
select argument_name, position, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale
from user_arguments X
where package_name = 'WRAPPER_PKG'
    and object_name = 'WRAPPER_TF'
    and in_out = 'OUT'
    and data_level = 2
order by sequence
;
```

... gives us a nice view on the fields defined in the record type:

```
ARGUMENT_NAME               POSITION DATA_TYPE  DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------- ----------
ID_DD_FILE                         1 NUMBER              22             38 
ID_DD_BATCH                        2 NUMBER              22             38 
TXT_FILE_NAME                      3 VARCHAR2          2000                
DETECTED_TYPE                      4 VARCHAR2            32                
IS_CORRECT_FILE_NAME               5 CHAR                 1                
TARGET_SYSTEM                      6 VARCHAR2          2000                
DELIVERING_SYSTEM                  7 VARCHAR2          2000                
CONTENT_ABBREVIATION               8 VARCHAR2          2000                
DELIVERING_UNIT                    9 VARCHAR2          2000                
PERIOD                            10 VARCHAR2             3                
IS_DELTA                          11 CHAR                 1                
IS_CORRECTIVE                     12 CHAR                 1                
IS_DAILY                          13 CHAR                 1                
IS_MONTHLY                        14 CHAR                 1                
DELIVERY_DATE_STR                 15 VARCHAR2          2000                
DELIVERY_TIME_STR                 16 VARCHAR2          2000                
DELIVERY_DATE_TIME                17 DATE                                  
FILE_EXTENSION                    18 VARCHAR2          2000
```

Comment: Looks like a good "workaround", but changing from boolean to number is not an option. We are are currently at 11g, but will upgrade to 12c in a few months, I just wait and use those views. Thanx :)

Comment: You're welcome (... to accept the answer, if it suits you :-)).

Answer (score 1):

If the type is declared in the package, then no, you won't be able to do a simple query to find out more information about the type. You might perhaps be able to do some fancy regular expression against the user/all_source table though.

If the type was created at the schema level, eg. `create type ...`, then you'd be able to use one or more of the following to find out information about them:

```
select * from user_types;

select * from user_type_attrs;

select * from user_coll_types;
```